# Is it possible to use SUM - CASE - IF together?

Tags: mysql

When I try to use this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN IF(SUM(CASE WHEN "b.count_students_status" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1, 1, 0) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

It says Query Error: Improper usage of Group Function

Below is the complete code:

```
   SELECT 
  "a.batch" AS Batch,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN IF(
        SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN "b.count_students_status" = 1 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
          END
        ) >= 1,
        1,
        0
      ) = 1 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS Payments_Not_Received 
FROM
  "DBU - Complete" 
WHERE "a.suspended" = 'no' 
GROUP BY "a.batch"
```

I wanted to convert the status to 1, if there are multiple occurrences and then sum the total occurrences.

Any help please - I am using ZOHO to build the query?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reference the result of the `GROUP BY` before is has run. Try something like this:

```
select t.BATCH,
sum(case when t.pnr >=1 then 1 else 0 end) as Payments_Not_Received
from
(
select 
a.batch as BATCH,
SUM(CASE WHEN "b.count_students_status" = 1 THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
    END) as pnr
from yourTable a
WHERE a.suspended = 'no'
group by a.batch
) t
group by t.BATCH;
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the answer; however, it still gives an error "Sorry, currently Zoho Reports does not support SELECT query in FROM clause." Any help please?